# Using StorageLibrary in order to listen for file changes UWP

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I recently found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201) article in response to listening for file changes in the universal windows platform. I want to be able to specify a folder and listen for the creation/deletion, and movement of files and folders within it. Other methods I found include creating an observable collection and setting a method for the CollectionChanged event to handle the change, however that doesn't give me access to what exactly changed. Using a StorageLibrary like the example in the article seems to be the best route, however StorageLibraries are created from KnownFolderIds. Is it worth looking into adding my specified folder to the list of KnownFolderIds, or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

As [the article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201) mentioned, there are two types of change notifications: **Foreground Change Events** and **Background Change Notifications**.

[image]
For foreground change events, it can be used for any folders or libraries but only available when the app is running in foreground. For background change notifications, it can keep monitoring even when the app isn't running but only works for named libraries. So for your question, it depends on your particular scenario. You can choose one of them according to your requirement.

However, [KnownFolderId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolderid) is an enumeration, there is no way to add a folder to it. What we can do is using [StorageLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagelibrary.requestaddfolderasync) method to prompt the user to select a folder, and then adds the folder to one of the known library. And besides these two change notifications, for now, there is no other way to monitor file system change in UWP.